# Add One Object from Collection to another Collection

Tags: vba, excel, class

I've created a class called `CASN` within this class has a couple variables (which aren't really important here). Basically what I'm trying to do is, create a new collection and add items based on a specific criteria from the original collection.

Once the `compare` collection is created, then I will compare the two collections against each other and ONLY keep the duplicate values in another new `result` collection.

```
Public Function FindDuplicates(col As Collection, wk As String) As Collection

   Dim numOrig As CASN
   Dim numComp As CASN
   Dim result As Collection
   Dim compare As Collection

   For Each numOrig In col
      If (numOrig.Week <> wk) Then
         Set numComp = New CASN
         Debug.Print numOrig.Addressxl   '''' ERROR HERE
         numComp.Addressxl = numOrig.Addressxl
         compare.Add numComp
      End If
   Next numOrig

'''''''''' OTHER PROCEDURES

End Function
```

**EDIT:**

I removed a lot of unnecessary code and trying to isolate the issue to to the above code. It seems as though the collection getting passed through into the function is having issues?

> Run-time error '13':
>
> Type mismatch

Comment: What is the type of `CASN.Addressxl`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Omg... How did I miss this... It was `Range` LOL

Comment: Other than that silly mistake, am I doing this properly?

Comment: Hard to tell, seems like a lot of code is missing. I'd pass the parameters `ByVal` though. Here that procedure could legally change the value of `wk`, or `Set col = Nothing`, and the calling code would be F'd.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I can confirm it all works, the only thing is that I forgot to do `Set compare = New Collection`. Is this the only way to add items from one collection to another? Or is there a faster/more efficient approach?

Comment: Seems fine. Collections are *made for this*, and you're iterating them the way they should be (i.e. with a `For Each` loop).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Debug.Print` statement is trying to convert `CASN.Addressxl` to a `String`, and failing to do that.

Verify the types involved.